# Slow OpenVPN tunnel

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn

I have a tunnel set up between two AWS regions. Using iperf, I saw that if I connect two machines directly (through the internet), I get about 100mb/s. If I use the tunnel, I get 10mb/s.

Is there a way to speed things up?

Here's my config:

```
proto tcp-server
port 1996
dev tun-us-east-1
remote <public IP>
route 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
ifconfig 10.248.0.1 10.248.0.2
keepalive 10 120
secret ovpn.key
log /var/log/openvpn.log
persist-tun
persist-key

user nobody
group nogroup
```

The other side is basically the same. I tried using UDP but it's still quite slow. I also tried removing compression and even encryption but no real change.

Comment: If you're concerned about performance, using TCP is not going to help you.

Comment: @EEAA I agree. I'm also concerned about reliability, I'm using this tunnel for communication between services and I can't really have stuff be dropped. I think this is going to be a problem with UDP correct?

Comment: Of course you're using this for communication between services. Just like everyone else. ;) Layering TCP kills performance, as you have multiple TCP stacks that end up fighting each other. Use UDP, and the underlying TCP communication will handle communication issues, latency, and packet loss just the same as they would if no VPN were involved.

Comment: @EEAA Nice that makes sense! I will try that and then maybe mess with the MTU stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @EEAA, I switched back to UDP. I also added the following to my config file:

```
comp-lzo no
tun-mtu 1470
mssfix 1430
```

Now it's super fast!

Comment: It's a little bit strange because with your initial settings I've got 200-220 mbit/s between two t2.nano instances.

Comment: @ALex_hha Are they on the same region? And are they both under a VPC?

Comment: Yes, the same region (us-west-1), both under VPC. I have emulated delays with tc (~75ms) to simulate that instances are in a different regions. The speed was about 40-50 Mbit with default settings, and 60-80 with optimized one

Comment: @ALex_hha I think when the instances are in the same region, the networking infrastructure is different. That could explain the speed difference. Why not use VPC peering in your case?